# Dealing with JSON pagination in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to learn Javascript and AngularJS. In that context, I am writing an application that is utilizing the Spotify Web API to read and modify playlists. I have made a function that fetches the tracks in a playlist based on its ID, and this is working fine except for one thing. As stated in the Spotify Web API documentation, the request limit is 100 tracks. There is of course a URL to retrieve the next 100 tracks in the playlist, but I haven't figured out how to properly handle this. Below is my attempt to retrieve all tracks in a playlist, but this will just hang up the browser.

```
$scope.getPlaylistTracks = function (playlist_id) {

    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        Spotify.getPlaylistTracks($scope.currentUser["id"], playlist_id).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            var tracks = data.items;
            var next = data.next;

            while(next != null) {
                console.log("More than one page");
                console.log(data.next);
                $http.get(data.next, {
                    headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + $scope.token}
                }).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.status);
                    console.log(response.data);
                    next = data.next;
                    tracks.push.apply(tracks, response.data.items);
                }, function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data || "Request failed");
                    console.log(response.status);
                })
            }

            resolve(tracks);

        }, function(reason) {
            reject(reason);
        })
    });
}
```

If I do it like this instead, I am able to retrieve at most 200 tracks:

```
var tracks = data.items;

if(data.next != null) {
    console.log("More than one page");
    console.log(data.next);
    $http.get(data.next, {
        headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + $scope.token}
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.data);
        tracks.push.apply(tracks, response.data.items);
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response.data || "Request failed");
        console.log(response.status);
    })
}

resolve(tracks);
```

Comment: That while loop definitely isn't doing what you hope. Will be firing off probably thousands of requests. It's not going to wait each iteration for the request to be made. look in your network tab

Comment: Why do you need more than 100 at a time anyway? That's a lot for user to look through , can make requests for more when user needs them

Comment: The user is not going to look through the tracks, the application is. My intention is to detect (and later remove) duplicate tracks in a playlist, so I would need to fetch all of them, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working like intended by using the code below.

```
       $scope.fetchTracksFromPlaylist = function (playlist_id) {
            $scope.fetchPlaylistTracks(playlist_id).then(function(data) {
                $scope.setPlaylistTracks(data);
            })
        }

        $scope.fetchPlaylistTracks = function (playlist_id) {
            $scope.tracks = [];

            return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                Spotify.getPlaylistTracks($scope.currentUser["id"], playlist_id).then(
                    function (data) {
                        resolve(data);
                    }, function (reason) {
                        reject(reason);
                    })
            });
        }

        $scope.setPlaylistTracks = function (tracks) {

            $scope.tracks.push.apply($scope.tracks, tracks.items);

            if (tracks.next) {
                $scope.callSpotify(tracks.next, function(data) {
                   $scope.setPlaylistTracks(data);
                });
            }
        }

        $scope.callSpotify = function (url, callback) {
            $http.get(url, {
                headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + $scope.token}
            }).then(function (response) {
                callback(response.data);
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response.data || "Request failed");
                console.log(response.status);
            })
        }
```